# [ERROR] [1519888351.478412390]: Cannot identify '/dev/video0': 2, No such file or directory

Tags: ros-indigo, usb-cam, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, I'm trying to use `usb_cam-test.launch` in `usb_cam` package to read my web camera,  but it keeps returning error:

```
Cannot identify '/dev/video0': 2, No such file or directory
```

---

**Update:**

when i run lsusb devices are:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 045e:0772 Microsoft Corp. LifeCam Studio 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1c4f:0048 SiGma Micro 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 045e:0772 Microsoft Corp. LifeCam Studio 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 058f:a014 Alcor Micro Corp. Asus Integrated Webcam 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf3:3005 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3011 Bluetooth 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

how can run my camera? i have two LifeCam Studio cameras.

---

**Update 2:**

when i run

```
ls -ltrh /dev/video*
```

this give:

```
crw-r--r-- 1 root root 81, 0 Mar 1 01:10 /dev/video0
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284015/%5Berror%5D-%5B1519888351.478412390%5D:-cannot-identify-%27/dev/video0%27:-2,-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [zahra.kh](https://answers.ros.org/users/32216/zahra.kh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2018-03-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-01**:
Please don't create a new question to add information to a previous one (#q284010). You can always edit your question instead.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-01**:
@zahra.kh: I noticed that many of your questions have answers, but none are accepted as correct. Could you please take a few minutes and mark the ones that solved your problems as correct? It really helps out others that find your question so they may know a solution.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-01**:
Please don't use an *answer* to provide more information about your *question*. This isn't a forum,  please update your question instead. I moved the contents of your answer to your question.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-01**:
The main part of my answer was to run

```
ls -ltrh /dev/video*
```

What does this give? Please update your question with a copy and paste of the output from the terminal using the *preformatted text* (`101010`) button.

**Comment by [zahra.kh](https://answers.ros.org/users/32216/zahra.kh/) on 2018-03-01**:
when i run ls -ltrh /dev/video*, this give:
crw-r--r-- 1 root root 81, 0 Mar  1 01:10 /dev/video0

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-01**:
Again, please *update your question* when giving more information. Comments aren't the appropriate place for that.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-01**:
Is the camera turned on?

**Comment by [zahra.kh](https://answers.ros.org/users/32216/zahra.kh/) on 2018-03-01**:
i connected two cameras to laptop usbs!

**Comment by [zahra.kh](https://answers.ros.org/users/32216/zahra.kh/) on 2018-03-01**:
when i run roslaunch usb_cam usb_cam-test.launch video_device:=/dev/video0 this error is created:
Cannot open '/dev/video0': 13, Permission denied

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-01**:
Ok, are the cameras turned on?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-01**:
Please **update your question** when you have new information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/348842):

> To list all video devices picked up by the kernel
>
> ```
> ls -ltrh /dev/video*
> ```
>
> To list all devices attached to USB use `lsusb` ; to list all devices attached to PCI use `lspci`

Once you identify which device is your webcam, start the `usb_cam_node` node with

```
roslaunch usb_cam usb_cam-test.launch video_device:=<your-device>
```

where `<your-device>` is your webcam.

---

**Edit:**

Try adding yourself to the user group

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER
```

Now, I found this by some [googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=ubuntu+%2Fdev%2Fvideo0+permission+denied).

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zahra.kh](https://answers.ros.org/users/32216/zahra.kh/) on 2018-03-01**:
i run sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER , but my problem isn't solved!

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-01**:
Again, please **update your question with new information**. Comments are not the appropriate place for updates.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-01**:
Also,

> but my problem isn't solved

isn't helpful. What is the result? (Please *update your question* with that information.)